# Symmetry and correlation coefficients

Tags: probability, correlation

Let's say I have two variables $B_1$ and $B_2$ such as $B_1 = (b_{1,1}, b_{1,2}, ..., b_{1,n})$ where $\forall i, \space 0 \leq b_{1,i} \leq x$ and $B_2 = x - B_1 = (x - b_{1,1}, x - b_{1,2}, ..., x - b_{1,n})$.

I experimented that the two [Pearson correlation coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) $\rho_1 = corr(A, B_1)$ and $\rho_2 = corr(A, B_2)$ where $A$ is an arbitrary variable where *symmetric* (*i.e.* $\rho_1 = -\rho_2$).

I tried to prove this assumption with the definition of correlation but without any success...

Could someone help me how to prove this result from the definition which is: $corr(A,B) = \frac{cov(A, B)}{\sigma_A\sigma_B}$?

Comment: If x is an constant you can simply drop it, because it does not have any variance. Btw i would not call it symmetric but rather anti-symmetric.

Comment: @MrYouMath The relation of $a=-b$ is symmetric.  $\forall a\,\forall b: \Big((a=-b) \to (b=-a)\Big)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the definitions of correlation, and covariance: $$\begin{align}\rho_i~=~&\mathsf {Corr}(A,B_i)\\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf {Cov}(A,B_i)}{\sigma_A\sigma_{B_i}} \\[2ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf E(A~B_i)-\mathsf E(A)~\mathsf E(B_i)}{\sigma_A~\sqrt{~\mathsf E\Big(\big(B_i-\mathsf E(B_i)\big)^2\Big)~}} \end{align}$$

So on inspection we should find that if $B_2 = x-B_1$, then $\rho_2=-\rho_1$ for any $A$.
$$\begin{align}\rho_2 ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf E(A~B_2)-\mathsf E(A)~\mathsf E(B_2)}{\sigma_A~\sqrt{~\mathsf E\Big(\big(B_2-\mathsf E(B_2)\big)^2\Big)~}} \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf E(A~(x-B_1))-\mathsf E(A)~\mathsf E(x-B_1)}{\sigma_A~\sqrt{~\mathsf E\Big(\big((x-B_1)-\mathsf E(x-B_1)\big)^2\Big)~}}
\\[1ex] \ddots &\end{align}$$

Comment: Is it because $\text{E}(B_2) = \text{E}(x - B_1) = -\text{E}(B_1)$? Also, I don't understand how do you get the final expression of the correlation. Shouldn't it be $\frac{\text{E}(AB_i) - \text{E}(A)\text{E}(B_i)}{\sigma_A\sqrt{\text{E}((B_i - \text{E}(B_i))^2)}}$?

Comment: It might have been a step too far.  Basically: $\mathsf E(B_2)=x-\mathsf E(B_1)$, $\mathsf E(AB_2)=x\mathsf E(A)-\mathsf E(AB_1)$, etc.

Comment: Well, thanks. It is now clear how to get $-\text{E}(AB_1) + \text{E}(A)\text{E}(B_1)$ as numerator. But I am still not able to get $\sigma_A\sqrt{\text{E}((B_1 - E(B_1))^2)}$ as denominator, should I start by considering the remarkable identity?

Comment: @Raoul722 Begin with $~\sqrt{\mathsf E\Big( \big( B_2-\mathsf E(B_2) \big)^2 \Big)} ~=~ \sqrt{\mathsf E\Big( \big( x-B_1-( x-\mathsf E(B_1) ) \big)^2 \Big)}~$ then simplify.